# Accessing the Properties in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to ask why use ' sphere' to access transform.position which is **sphere.transform.position** in script1. But in script2, we can directly assess transform.Rotate without any objects before it, why not write as: **sphere.transform.Rotate**?

**script1**

```
void Update () {

}
private IEnumerator SphereIndicator(Vector3 pos)
{
    GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive (PrimitiveType.Sphere);
    sphere.transform.position = pos;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
    Destroy(sphere)
}
```

**script2**

```
void Update () {
    if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX) {
        transform.Rotate (0, Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * sensitivityHor, 0);
    }
```

Comment: **Script2** modifies rotation transform of currently parented object. **Script1** will modify rotation transform of the object which is not related to that particular script. This is not a question related to Unity but the question about basics of OOP.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-transform.html), `.transform` lets you access Transform component of the Game Object. If you just use `transform`, it is the same, as if you would use `this.transform`, it will return the Transform component attached to the same Game Object that the caller script is attached to.

So in your example, in the **srcipt1** you are calling the Transform component from different Game Object, but in the **script2** you are calling the component of the same Game Object.